# Can't activate my Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation

I found the key below the battery but still can't use it. The "some of these characters can't be used in the product key" appears every time.

Comment: Windows 10 Keys are not printed on the COA on the device. Are you sure the license you are attempting to use is a Windows 10 license?

Comment: Post a screenshot of the sticker.

Comment: If you submit a screenshot of the stick, remove any information, and prevent the use of your license (not that it would do anyone any good to attempt to use an OEM license).

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working, look on your PC/Laptop's original box. They sometimes copy the key on there in case. I can't say for sure though. Are you sure that what you're seeing under the battery is your Windows key?